# VB6 DAO Connection to SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, vb6, dao

**INTRODUCTION** (tldr; question down below)

First off, yes I know DAO:

1. is obsolete
2. no longer supported
3. inefficient for SQL
4. sucks in general

So answers along those lines aren't helpful to the problem.

I've long since shifted my preferences to NHibernate and other means of connecting to data. However, I'm on a legacy project where the first stage of the plan is to migrate the data from many Access databases to a single SQL Server instance. Easy enough. The data migration has been done and works fine.

However, the application is VB6 code using DAO to connect to Access and I need to change this as minimally as possible for the first stage.  The next phase (soon) is to convert the whole application to an ASP.NET MVC site hitting SQL Server properly.

As I search around for how to properly structure the DAO `OpenDatabase()` function to hit SQL Server, all the answers are the aforementioned *"Why do you want to do that?" "You should learn ADODB!" "DAO is for suckers!"* nonsense that never addresses the actual question asked. Sadly the original question remains in the search engine even though it's marked "solved" on particular forums, etc...

**SO... THE QUESTION**

Given all of this, is there ANYONE who still remembers how to connect to SQL Server using DAO `OpenDatabase`?

*Yes, this is comparable to drilling a hole in a piece of wood with a brace and bit? Sure a power drill is better, smarter, faster, and all that goodness... but sometimes the old ways are required.*

Comment: Why don't you use SQL Server's built-in tools to import the data from Access?

Comment: Not to be rude, but how does that answer my question in the slightest?  Getting the data from Access to SQL Server is not a concern or part of the question at all (that part is already done as implied in the question above)

I need the VB6 application to connect VIA DAO to SQL Server where the data is already located.

Comment: I had to migrate recently a VB6 with DAO application from SQL7 to SQL 2016, and the process was almost straight forward.  I didn't change anything in code, except old SQL Syntax that is obsolete now.  So, what is your issue?  Can you be more precise?

Comment: It is difficult to provide useful information when you don't ask a very specific question. Saying "how do I structure ..." implies a question that is far too broad for SO. But if your question is along the lines of "how do I connect to a sql server database using dao OpenDatabase method", then it seems the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/workspace-opendatabase-method-dao) has such an example. Is that not useful?

Comment: @DanielBlais Thanks for attempting to help.  Not sure though what's not clear.  I simply need an example of the DAO OpenDatabase() method calling into a SQL Server database.  The ones in the code I'm fixing are calling into MDB files and that syntax is obviously invalid for SQL: 

OpenDatabase(gDATABASE_PATH & "MDBNAME.mdb", False, False, ";pwd=AccessPassword")

Comment: @SMor - The question is pretty specific.  Not sure what you think is too broad about it.  Thanks for the link to the doc, but I found that early on in google searching (way before I asked here).  Does not have a SQL example unfortunately.

Comment: I used ODBC.  So, here how I open SQL connection with DAO : `connect = "DSN=<odbcname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>;DATABASE=<database>"
Set datab = rdoEnvironments(0).OpenConnection("", rdDriverCompleteRequired, False, connect)`  This is the solution for us, for having less changed to do in our old app.  Note this is not the only way to do this.

Comment: @DanielBlais Thanks for the help.  Was hoping to just fire OpenDatabase() directly, but perhaps the OpenConnection will work.

If you post as a solution vs. comment on the question I'll mark it.  Thanks!

Comment: Tell me before if this solve your issue.

Comment: Remember you have to use 32 bits ODBC driver.  If you are on 64 bits system, take the good one (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`).  And I think I have used `SQL Server` driver.  SQL Native client are too recent for DAO (I think).  You may have to try many.

Comment: @DanielBlais - Your post led the way, thank you!  The format of the connection string was the key for me as well as the reminder to setup the ODBC as 32 bit (I'd done 64 bit forgetting it's the bitness of the consumer, not the system that is relevant)...  Those two pieces and instead of RDO, I was able to connect via DAO OpenDatabase as expected.  Please add answer and I'll upvote.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Also you can add ODBC linked tables to SQL Server, and copy table-to-table with Access.  SQL Server Migration Assistant can automate this for you.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but migrating the data is not in question.  That part as noted is already done (using SQL Import tool was a no-brainer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to migrate recently a VB6 with DAO application from SQL7 to SQL 2016, and the process was almost straight forward. I didn't change anything in code, except old SQL Syntax that is obsolete now.

I used ODBC. So, here how I open SQL connection with DAO :

```
connect = "DSN=<odbcname>;UID=<username>;PWD=<password>;DATABASE=<database>"
Set datab = rdoEnvironments(0).OpenConnection("", rdDriverCompleteRequired, False, connect)
```

This is the solution for us, for having less changed to do in our old app. Note this is not the only way to do this.

Remember you have to use 32 bits ODBC driver. If you are on 64 bits system, take the good one (`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`). And I think I have used `SQL Server` driver. SQL Native client are too recent for DAO (I think). You may have to try many.

Comment: Thank you... I did have the 64 bit ODBC setup and not 32 bit.  That correction and the proper structure of the connectionstring were the keys.  Instead of RDO and OpenConnection, was still able to use ADO and OpenDatabase to minimize my code changes.

Answer (score 3):

I think one way you could do that isuse an ODBC connection.
On Administrative tools form control panel y can add an ODBC Source to you SQL Server.
After doing that, you could try this:

```
Dim worksp As Workspace
Dim conexString As String
Dim base As Variant
Set worksp = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Let conexString = "OBDC;DSN=SQLDNSNAME;UID=;PWD="
Set base = worksp.OpenDatabase("BDDNAME", False, False, conexString)
```

Comment: You're Welcome, happy to help u